# Links inside of display block link issue, both links activate

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, rollover

I have a list of rollover blocks. The block itself is a link to one page. Inside the block are two other links, text, to different pages. When you click on one of these links, both that link and the block link execute, causing two windows to load. How can I make it so when clicking on the text the block link does not execute?

Thanks!

```
echo "<div class='feedcontent'
           onclick='show_thumbnail($pageid,$revid, this)'
           id='newsitem-$pageid-$revid'>";

echo " <a href='javascript:void;'
             onclick='load_wikitrust(\"$wktrust_url\");'>edited</a><br>";
$aname=substr($wkarticle, 0, 27);
echo " <a href='javascript:void;'
             onclick='window.open(\"$wkarticle_url\")'>$aname</a>";
echo " on <span class='timeline_timestamp'>$timestamp</span>";
echo "</div>
```

So, for example when you click on the article name ($aname) both the onclick link showing the thumbnail as well as the onclick link to open the window with the article load. This is just a snippet of the code inside the block which is defined by the class feedcontent.

Comment: i updated the question with some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `event.stopPropagation();` for that:

http://jsfiddle.net/jPYka/

```
<div class="outer" onclick="alert('outer container clicked'); return false">
    <div class="inner" onclick="alert('inner 1 clicked'); event.stopPropagation();">inner 
        1
    </div>
    <div class="inner" onclick="alert('inner 2 clicked');">inner 
        2
    </div>
</div>​
```

notice how the onclick event of the outer div is prevented, when clicking the first container.

Comment: worked like a charm. gosh thank you so much! you saved me a ton of time!!

Answer (score 1):

Even though it might be working, 
**You can't nest href**,

> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A
>   element must not contain any other A elements.

**w3.org** - 
[View full details on their page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

Comment: what i'm trying to do is very common. one example is on the facebook message system. when you rollover your list of friends on the right hand side a small icon appears. the rollover block allows you to message the user in question, while the icon goes to the user's profile, but not both.

Comment: If you inspect this part of Facebook code, you will see that there is no <a> nested.

Comment: Before you update your question with code, I thought you were nesting <a>: "The block itself is a link to one page. Inside the block are two other links".

Answer (score 0):

According to HTML specification, you can't put an `a` tag inside an other one.

> [**The `a` element**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-a-element)
>
> > **Categories:** Interactive content, Flow content.
> >     **Content Model:** Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

Fix your HTML in order to have a correct behavior!